# Codeigniter 4 Content Security Policy

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-security-policy, codeigniter-4

I've pretty much got the gist of the content security policy from Codeigniter 4's user guide.
From their example, I'll need to add the following 'runtime configuration' for my website's font:

```
$response->CSP->addStyleSrc('fonts.googleapis.com');
```

What I CAN'T seem to work out from the user guide - is where do I put this? It's not in `app/Config/ContentSecurityPolicy.php` and when I tried to input it into my `BaseController` I got a syntax error.

Does it go in my `Controller`, for every single function, or have I missed a trick?

All guidance appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the complete error you are getting when you place csp code in BaseController. Which method?